# Active record pattern for a subscription service website

Tags: php, unit-testing

I just jumped to a new project, which uses the active record pattern. It's a subscription service website.

I have the following `User` object that extends a framework specific `ORM` object:

```
class User extends ORM {

    public function isSubscriber() 
    {

        $activeSubscription = $this->subscriptions->where('active','=',1)->find_all();
        return $activeSubscription->count();

    }

}
```

In client code, I have the following code:

```
class Test_Controller extends Controller {

    public function test()
    {

        // Framework speific way to get a current user
        // returns User orm
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();

        var_dump($user->isSubscriber());


    }

}
```

As you see, it's very straightforward and easy to understand. What's bothering me is that there's no way to test this simple `User` object unless I hack it.

The problem is that inside `ORM` objects, it uses a singleton pattern (something like `Database::getInstance()`) to get a database object and uses it to query to database, making it impossible to properly mock it.

I extracted `isSubscriber()` from `User` to a service like this:

```
class SubscriberVerificationService {

    public function __construct(SubscriptionRepositoryInterface $subscriptionRepository)
    {

        $this->subscriptionRepository = $subscriptionRepository;

    }

    public function isSubscriber(User $user)
    {

        $subscriptions = $this->subscriptionRepository->findActiveSubscriptionsByUserId($user->id);
        return count($subscriptions);

    }

}
```

**Client code**

```
class Test_Controller {

    public function __construct(SubscriberVerificationService $subscriberVerificationService)
    {
        $this->subscriberVerificationService = $subscriberVerificationService;
    }

    public function test()
    {

        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
        var_dump($this->subscriberVerificationService->isSubscriber($user));

    }

}
```

Now I can properly mock `SubscriptionRepositoryInterface` and and `User` objects in my test.

I feel like this is the way to go, but I just want to hear advice from people who use the active record pattern day-to-day.

It doesn't have to be a repository (`SubscriptionRepositoryInterface`) in the service. It can be a `Subscription` `ORM` as long as I can mock it.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm going to have nightmares now... but what hellish framework are you using? An ORM that is built around a singleton DB? ffs, that's just horrible. Oh, and as an asside: each time you call `$user->isSubscriber()`, do you really _want_ to perform that query? I mean: why not assign it to a property and return that? It's what most ORM's would do, after all

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem // Exactly what I want to ask to the previous maintainer. The framework is Kohana. So the actual code saves the result to a property for caching. I tried to make it simple enough to make people understand.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid hacking the code, if possible. Instead, you should have a test environment with a testing database. `Database::getInstance()` should use a configuration file containing the database connection parameters. It should configure itself to use the testing database when running unit tests.

Comment: Well, isn't that an integration test?